# What's the value of CMSG_ALIGN macro

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Is it right to say the value of `CMSG_ALIGN(i)` is the minimum value of multiple of 8  and  `>=`i if `i` is an unsigned int variable?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<50; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", CMSG_ALIGN(i));
    }
}
```

Output I get:

```
/*       i              CMSG_ALIGN(i)
 *
 *       0                     0
 *       [1,8]                 8
 *       [9,16]                16
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it right to say the value of CMSG_ALIGN(i) is the minimum value of
>   multiple of 8 and >=i if i is an unsigned int variable?

No. The alignment for a given value is not necessarily `8` on all platforms. If it were to be `8` always, `CMSG_ALIGN()` wouldn't be necessary at all.

You are probably on a 64-bit system. So it's aligned on 8 byte boundary. But if you run the same code on a 32-bit platform, you would probably see that it's a 4 byte alignment.

Note that [`CMCG_ALIGN()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) returns `size_t`. So `%zu` is the correct format string to print a `size_t` value.

Comment: Thanks! I test sizeof(struct cmsghdr) and the value is 16.    The three members are cmsg_len, cmsg_level and cmsg_type. Why sizeof(struct cmsghdr) is not 12?

Comment: [struct padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). This is done for alignment. See: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: In my question sizeof(struct cmsghdr), In the book the member ‘cmsg_len’ is ‘socklen_t’ , 4B, (total 12B for 3 members)but I find that ‘cmsg_len’ is ‘size_t’ , 8B (total 16B for 3 members)in my system. I use command vi -t cmsghdr in the directory /usr/include